# next-auth / urql - access the access token to set Authorization header in urql client

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, urql

I am using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) to manage JWT tokens and sessions for my next.js application. I'm also using [urql](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql) as the GraphQL client. I initialise the urql client in a file as follows:

```js
import { createClient } from 'urql';

const client = createClient({
  url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  fetchOptions: () => {
    return {
      headers: {}, // I'd like to set Auth header here...
    };
  },
});

export default client;
```

And then this is added to `_app.tsx` as follows:

```js
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from 'next-auth/client';
import { Provider as GraphqlProvider } from 'urql';
import client from '../graphql/client';

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { session } = pageProps;

  return (
    <GraphqlProvider value={client}>
      <AuthProvider session={session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AuthProvider>
    </GraphqlProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nothing fancy at this stage.

Now my issue is that I want to be able to access the access token to add an `Authorization` header in client, however because this bit of code exists outside of a React component I can't use the `useSession` hook provided by next-auth.

Can anyone suggest the best way to approach this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get a very helpful response from one of the `next-auth` maintainers on how to handle this scenario: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/1806

Important points are to have the `AuthProvider` as the most parent component in `_app.tsx`, then create a `useClient` hook that you pass to urql's provider:

`/graphql/client.ts`

```js
import { createClient } from '@urql/core';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client';
import * as React from 'react';

/**
 * Get GraphQL Client in browser environments (frontend).
 *
 * If the user has an active session, it will add an accessToken to all requests
 */
const useClient = (options?: RequestInit) => {
  const [session] = useSession();
  const token = session?.accessToken;
  // const handleError = useErrorHandler();

  return React.useMemo(() => {
    const client = createClient({
      url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
      fetchOptions: () => {
        return {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
            ...(options?.headers ? options.headers : {}),
          },
        };
      },
    });

    return client;
  }, [options, token]);
};

export default useClient;
```

then create the urql provider, passing in the client that you get from `useClient` hook:

`/graphql/provider.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'urql';
import useClient from './client';

interface GraphqlProviderProps {}

const GraphqlProvider: React.FC<GraphqlProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const client = useClient();

  return <Provider value={client}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default GraphqlProvider;
```

And then use this as child to `AuthProvider` in `_app.tsx`

```js
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from 'next-auth/client';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import GraphqlProvider from '../graphql/provider';
import '../styles/index.css';

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { session } = pageProps;

  return (
    <AuthProvider session={session}>
      <GraphqlProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </GraphqlProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Finally, you can pause all `useQuery` requests until `session` is initialised:
`/pages/index.tsx`

```js
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/client';
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'urql';

interface HomeProps {}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({}) => {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();

  const QUERY = `
  query {
    users {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
  `;

  const request = useQuery({ query: QUERY, pause: !session });
  console.log(request);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {!session && (
        <>
          Not signed in <br />
          <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
        </>
      )}

      {session && (
        <>
          Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
          <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And it works! You can see the auth header with valid jwt token in the network requests :-)